# Issue with Connected-App. Java-Salesforce Rest API

Tags: rest, oauth2, java, webserverflow

I am getting an issue from my local java application running at http://localhost:8080. When I enter this address inthe browser, I am being redirected to a login.salesforce.com, but I see a blank screen with the error error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration. I have configured the callback_uri as http://localhost:8080 which is where salesforce should redirect me after authentication. But instead shows me this error. Anyone ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

This explanation might help you to find the issue https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CzqNAAS